# How to proof that all points lie on a common circles.

Tags: circles, combinatorial-geometry

There are $n=2000$ points in the plane such that every for three of those points there exists a fourth of those points such that these four points lie on a common circle.

Proof that all $2000$ points lie on one common circle.

I can prove this for cases $n=5,6,7$ but I can't proof the case $n=2000$.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Why not having 500 circles that include 4 points each? This seems to be an erroneous claim.

Comment: @Moti Pick one point from each of $3$ of your $500$ circles; the circle through *those* three points is supposed to contain a fourth point in the set, but your construction doesn't guarantee that.

Answer (score 1):

An intuitive hint from me would be circumcenter and induction,

and you have to say something about collinear cases.